# Is this a finite Boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Suppose in a Boolean algebra that the finite sum of all the atoms gives $1$. Does it follow that this Boolean algebra is finite?

I was motivated by the following:
 [Does there exist an infnite Boolean algebra with only one atom?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980470/does-there-exist-an-infnite-boolean-algebra-with-only-one-atom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Given such a Boolean algebra $B$ with finitely many atoms $a_i$ such that $\vee_i a_i=1$, if $b\ B$ then we have $$b=b\wedge \vee a_i=\vee b\wedge a_i.$$
Each term in the latter join is either $0$ or an atom, so $b$ is a finite join of atoms, and a simple cardinality argument shows $B$ must be finite.

Comment: That’s it! I forgot that obvious step! Therefore the only options are the various combinations of the atoms. Thank you very much